# Using Groovy TemplateEngines with large (>64k) template

Tags: groovy

How can I use **SimpleTemplateEngine** or **GStringTemplateEngine** to process a template larger than 65535 characters?

I receive the following error:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
>   SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 5614: String too long. The given string is 198495 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed.

I'm building the template using the following code:

```
def templateEngine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def binding = [:]
templateEngine
    .createTemplate(new FileReader("input.txt))
    .make(binding)
    .writeTo(new FileWriter(new File("output.txt")))
```

I found **JIRA 3487** related to this issue: [GStringTemplateEngine fails to work with >64K strings](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3457) .

I've thought about chunking the input but that brings it's own complications like making sure not to break in the middle of an expression.

I would appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some replacements for `GStringTemplateEngine` These can can handle large Strings.

https://github.com/mbjarland/groovy-streaming-template-engine

https://github.com/mbknor/gt-engine

Comment: Not sure how I missed that project when I was searching for a solution.  Clearly my Google-Fu needs work.

Comment: groovy-streaming-template-engine does not work for me. It fails (java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!) for my approx. 250KB template exactly like the groovy built-in template engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `GStringTemplateEngine` instead. From the javadoc:

> Processes template source files substituting variables and expressions
>   into placeholders in a template source text to produce the desired
>   output using a streaming approach. This engine has equivalent
>   functionality to the SimpleTemplateEngine but creates the template
>   using writable closures making it potentially more scalable for large
>   templates or in streaming scenarios.

You will probably get away with simply replacing `new SimpleTemplateEngine()` with `new GStringTemplateEngine()`, but should of course test it.

Comment: Now that was a surprise. After some testing it seems like it fails if there is one large chunk of text (>64K) within the template that does not contain any variables. At least it works for me on ~100K files when variables are spread all over. If the text is very large, though (I got this on a 550K file with lots and lots of variables) another limit related to the implementation of this class starts occurring (method too long). A pity, really. This shouldn't be too hard to get right, but nobody seem very interested in fixing it.

Comment: Same problem here. Too bad this cannot be fixed. Real bummer.